# Jetpack Compose: UnsupportedOperationException when adding Entries to MPAndroidCharts dynamically

Tags: android-view, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines, mpandroidchart, kotlin-flow

I try to display live data in an MPAndroidChart hosted in an `AndroidView`.

I get the graph but an `UnsupportedOperationException` happens when I call `addEntry()` to update the graph dynamically. Am I doing something wrong?

You find a demo repo in the comments.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyLineChart() {
    val mainViewModel = viewModel()
    val sensorData = mainViewModel.sensorFlow.collectAsState(SensorModel(0F,0F)).value

    AndroidView(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        factory = { context ->
            val lineChart = LineChart(context)
            var entries = listOf(Entry(1f,1f))

            val dataSet = LineDataSet(entries, "Label").apply { color = Color.Red.toArgb() }

            val lineData = LineData(dataSet)
            lineChart.data = lineData
            lineChart.invalidate()

            lineChart
        }){

        try {
            Log.d("TAG", "MyLineChart: Update --- Current thread id: ${Thread.currentThread()}")

            it.data.dataSets[0].addEntry(Entry(sensorData.x, sensorData.y))
            it.lineData.notifyDataChanged()
            it.notifyDataSetChanged()
            it.invalidate()
        } catch(ex: Exception) {
            Log.d("TAG", "MyLineChart: $ex")
        }
    }
}
```

The data is sent to the view via the following `ViewModel`:

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(@ApplicationContext var appContext: Context) : ViewModel()  {
    private var rand: Random = Random(1)

    val sensorFlow: Flow<SensorModel> = flow<SensorModel> {

        while (true) {
            delay(1000L)
            Log.d("TAG", "sensorFlow: Current thread id: ${Thread.currentThread()}")
            emit(SensorModel(rand.nextFloat(), rand.nextFloat()))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To reproduce the issue, I prepared a sample: https://gitlab.com/thorsten.weiss/androidchartlivedata.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass `entries` to `LineDataSet`, which is an immutable list.

This library seems to have a pretty bad API, because it doesn't ask for a modifiable list as a parameter, but at the same time it doesn't make it modifiable on its side. This causes you to try to modify the immutable list, which leads to an exception.

Replace

```
var entries = listOf(Entry(1f,1f))
```

with

```
val entries = mutableListOf(Entry(1f,1f))
```

p.s. I can't advise you another graph library as I haven't worked with any, but I would advise you to look for a library with a better API.

Comment: I didn't find any lib with advanced chart features that support Jetpack Compose / kotlin officially. Thanks for clarification - Now all makes sense. I tried it for hours to get working. I'm still at the beginning of my kotlin journey

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
        // it.data.dataSets[0].addEntry(Entry(sensorData.x, sensorData.y))
        
        val entryList =  mutableListOf<Entry>()            
        entryList.add(Entry(sensorData.x, sensorData.y))
        
        val dataSet = LineDataSet(entryList, "Label").apply {
            color = Color.Red.toArgb()
        }
        
        it.data = LineData(dataSet)
```

Comment: When you see the solution, it's obvious. But finding the root cause based on the exception was not that easy. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean of "see the solution"? I was the first one answer you topic, I provided above code before Philip Dukhov.

Comment: I didn't meant you - I meant me. Sorry for not writing it clearer. I really wanted to thank you and upvoted